# AngularJS values not visible in directive and template- html

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have the following directive in html:

```
<as-excel-download institutionId="vm.reportInstitution.id"></as-excel-download>
```

the directive looks like this:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('aposoft.common')
    .directive('asExcelDownload', asExcelDownload);

function asExcelDownload() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {                
            institutionId: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/common/exceldownload/asExcelDownload.html'
    };
    return directive;

    ////////////
}
})();
```

and the directive template looks like this:

```
<a href="/api/schedulerecordexcel/monthreport/{{institutionId}}">
  <img src="./Excel.PNG" alt="icon" />
</a>
```

and actually I don't know why {{institutionId}} is emty in directive template html. 
If I change **institutionId** into **vm** in every of the above files (which is the scope in controller) and access institution id over vm in directive template html than everything works fine.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you see anything in the `console`?

Comment: no, there is no error in the firefox firebug console.

Comment: Can you `console.log(institutionId)` inside the directive `link` to see what the value is of `institutionId` is? and maybe checked the passes value `vm.reportInstitution.id` for correctness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using wrong name as attribute, so basically this part:

```
<as-excel-download institutionId="vm.reportInstitution.id"></as-excel-download>
```

Should look like this:

```
<as-excel-download institution-id="vm.reportInstitution.id"></as-excel-download>
```